# How do i force a user to upgrade their browser without losing them?

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, browser, upgrade, user-management

There are several ways to persuade or force a user to upgrade IE. But when they do this, is there a way to pass a parameter so they end up back on your site once the upgrade is done?

Thanks